# detectar si es data:image/png o data:image/jpg para cargar una imagen en base64

Tags: php, base64

hola una pregunta hay alguna forma de detectar que tipo de imagen se esta cargando en un `<img>`
este es un ejemplo de mi codigo

```
$data = "https://www.imagen.com.mx/assets/img/imagen_share.png";
echo '<img src="data:image/$tipo;base64,"'.base64_decode($data).' alt="" />';
```

bien lo que intento es que detecte que si es png se añada la tag data:image/png y si es jpg data:image/jpg

Comment: No tienes guardado el $tipo de imagen en tu base de datos?

Comment: pero como hago que detecte ese tipo? no puedo guardarla sin que este detecte si el enlace termina en png o jpg

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mime-content-type.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para detectar el tipo de imagen...

```
<?php
$file = "http://localhost/carpetas/cronjob.png";
$image_mime = getimagesize($file);
var_dump($image_mime);
echo "El tipo de imagen es: <b>".$image_mime['mime']."</b>";
 ?>
```

Resultado...

```
array (size=6)
  0 => int 1670
  1 => int 65
  2 => int 3
  3 => string 'width="1670" height="65"' (length=24)
  'bits' => int 8
  'mime' => string 'image/png' (length=9)

El tipo de imagen es: image/png
```

---

## Adaptación a tu código

```
$data = "https://www.imagen.com.mx/assets/img/imagen_share.png";

$image_mime = getimagesize($data);

if(isset($image_mime['mime'])) {

    $tipo = explode('/',$image_mime['mime']);

    echo '<img src="data:image/'.$tipo[1].';base64,"'
          .base64_decode($data).' alt="" />';
}
```